# My App keeps crashing when i try to retrieve data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Please I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase into a RecyclerView using onDataChange function. When i begin typing the username into my search box my app crashes. my logcat keeps pointing to this line of code
`val user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)` but i dont know exactly what to do, i'm new to programming.  [Here is a screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4jEX.png) and [that of the data i'm trying to retrieve from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zngUc.png). I also wrote out the code below, although it's the same with that of the screenshot. Please help me out. Thank you

```
private fun searchUser(input: String)
{
    val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        .child("Users")
        .orderByChild("fullname")
        .startAt(input)
        .endAt(input + "\uf8ff")
    query.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener
    {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)
        {
            mUser?.clear()
            for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children)
            {
                val user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                if (user != null)
                {
                    mUser?.add(user)
                }
            }
            userAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }


        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)
        {

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please open the logcat and see the error when the app crashes and paste it here.. Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Please add logs from the logcat

Comment: the question has a link to the screenshot of my logcat. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't say anything about the error.

Comment: @AliApochi Please share that specific part of the logcat where the error/exception is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think i was having the same issue. When I read data from the database everything worked fine, but then when i called it somewhere else my app just crashed. So i had to put all the code where i used that data inside the listener. For Example:

**WRONG WAY:**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("examplePath/exPath").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        myObject = snapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);
                                        
                                    }
    
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                                    }
                                });
    
    
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), myObject.getVariable(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**RIGHT WAY:**

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("examplePath/exPath").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                            myObject = snapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), myObject.getVariable(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            
                                        }
        
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        
                                        }
                                    });
```